# How to create a dataframe where two columns have values that depend on each other?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how to create the vectors in my dataframe when the table I am trying to create has columns that depend on each other. For example, I want to assign the number 0 in one column to match up with a variable I am putting in another column ( for ex the number 2) so that the rows are identical, every time that a row has a 2, the column next to its row will have 0. Hopefully this makes sense.

Thank you!

I havent tried anything out yet tbh

Comment: Can you reproduce a sample dataset and a sample of what you intend to get for us to understand the problem better, that would help us to assist in giving you your desired output

Comment: Make a 2-column matrix or data.frame with the pairs of values, e.g.: `data.frame(a=c(0,1), b=c(2,3))` and then you can subset this paired dataset by either value.